# (Typescript) Make all objects point to the same values

Tags: typescript

I have a class with a lot of CSS properties, something like this:

```
export class CustomDropdown {

  class_name: String
  name: String
  font_family: String = "Varela Round"
  border_color: String =  "#C0C0C0"
  speech_color: String = "#FFFFFF"
  font_color: String = "#1E1E1E"
  font_size_value: String
  radius_value: String
  ...
}
```

With it, I'm instancing many objects, each one of them affects the view-port in some way.

The thing is, when I change the `'font_family'` property of one object, I want all the others to be updated, regardless of which was altered.

So, if I set `ObjectA.font_family = 'arial'`, every other object will be updated with `font_family = 'arial'`. I wanted to do this with the minimum amount of functions as possible. 
 All of them should be **'pointing'** to the same value.

Does TS support something like this? If not, what's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: You want a `static` property?

Comment: Oh, it seems like.. yes

Comment: Didn't knew what static was until today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [a `static` property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#static-properties) - these are properties on the *class itself*, rather than each of the instances.

```js
export class CustomDropdown {

  class_name: String
  name: String
  static font_family: String = "Varela Round"
  border_color: String =  "#C0C0C0"
  speech_color: String = "#FFFFFF"
  font_color: String = "#1E1E1E"
  font_size_value: String
  radius_value: String
  ...
}
```

Since it's a *class* property, you have to access it by referring to the class:

```
//read
let currentFontFamily = CustomDropdown.font_family;

//write
CustomDropdown.font_family = newFontFamily;
```

[Check a small example on the TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=25&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCCuEAuB7AtgEQE4oA4BMUB3AO2gG8BYAKGmhLDQFMAuaAZSSwEsSBzGnWRgk3YNABmKEkgD6ExtxABPNpx79oAXmgAiAGpgsTcNABKKeCXy7B0YNORZ4wVFgAUDZmq68+ASgo7OiQAC24IADovJm16RiYAbjsAXxo7XA0kd38fDT4g2jpoYyR4LDIAAwBZZXjmaAjoABJyMIjohJToMGtoNDqpGUlFFUaYVoRkdGw8QlJIobkFNCVlFMrkorTqHZoQJiRofBwCYhIARjiSJiI4RFRMU-mSd11pJl1-LYOjk7nzgAma63e7TJ4A0hvJBEFBfLY0BwkCAoA6REAoPhvAC0uOgACMmFJjNBcdj4YjHKimOjMe5-mdSBdIpleNl-N9KcjqbSsQyXoCWVkcpzqDQpo9ZoySItpMtRnUdLoACrcZgwAByoIsaF6ugR1CRKLRGKxujJPQkSCYWFJuIphqpJrp-POzNZMhFWyNPNN9OeQKFbK9NCAA) - open the developer console and click "Run" to see the output.